# List with positive numbers at the beginning and negative at the end

Tags: java

I'm just at the beginning but cannot find answer for my question. For any ideas will be very grateful.

I need a list which is filled for a half only with random positive digits, and another half only with random negative. The list should be added to a file

I do not understand how to do that. Any ideas?

For now I only can write String in a file like:

```
try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(numbers));
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(numbers)) {
    if (numbers.exists()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            wr.write(String.valueOf((i) + " "));
        }
        for (int a = -1; a >= -100; a--) {
            wr.write(String.valueOf((a) + " "));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What part are you having trouble with? Creating a random digit?

Comment: Sort the numbers in an Array with Arrays.sort and reverse it. The highest number (positive) is then the first entry and the lowest number (most likeley negative) will be last.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To post new questions you need to be clear describing the problem. You are mixing output and number generation: have you a problem with output random number or in generating them? Please update your question being more clear. Thanks

Comment: 1. [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java). 2. [The List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) 3. [Writing a list to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597373/writing-a-list-to-a-file)

Comment: I need a list which is filled for a half only with random positive digits, and another half only with random negative

Answer (score 2):

Try to work with `ArrayList` collection.

1. First fill the ArrayList with values.
2. Then sort this collection, for example with util method `Collections.sort()`.
3. Finally, work on creating file. Write method for saving sorted collection value by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> numbers = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(x -> random.nextInt(100) * (random.nextBoolean() ? -1 : 1)).boxed()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(Paths.get("D://test.txt"), numbers);
```

Generates 10 random numbers, reverses, collects to list and then writes to a file.
However, this doesnot handle duplicate random numbers.